# Increase scrolling speed of a Scrollview in Android

Tags: android, android-scrollview, onscrollchanged

I have 2 Scrollview in which scrolling of second `scrollview` is dependent on the scrolling of first `scrollview` as when first `scrollview` is scrolled i want to programatically scroll second `scrollview` 2 times faster than the first one. Anyone please share some idea to do it. Thanks.

On first `scrollview's onScrollChanged` i am trying to mange speed of second `scrollview` but not able to get the movement on second scrollview 2x faster

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
    super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldx, oldy);

  mSecondScrollView.smoothScrollTo(x, y * 2);
 }
```